# How to retrieve data from dialog window to mainwindow in pyqt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'maintest.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from test import Ui_Dialog

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def connect(self):
        self.updateWindow=QtGui.QDialog()
        self.ui_update=Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui_update.setupUi(self.updateWindow)
        self.updateWindow.show()

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(391, 248)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 60, 113, 27))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 100, 112, 34))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 391, 31))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "B1", None))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.connect)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

this was the main file code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'test.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog(object):

    def save_data(self):
        d= self.lineEdit.text()
        print(d)

    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(397, 219)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 100, 112, 34))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 60, 113, 27))
        self.lineEdit.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "B2", None))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.save_data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

this is the dialog file code

i have a main window form which has a lineedit l1 and a button B1 on it.
on clicking the button B1 a new dialog window opens.
dialog window has a lineedit l2 and a button B2. 
i write something in the l2 and then click b2 in dialog window.
how can  i send my data in l2 on clicking b2 to l1 in mainwindow and also close dialog window after button b2 click and return control to mainwindow

Comment: show your code, please

Comment: can i email some of it?

Comment: put it here please

Comment: Now the problem is that i can't send data back to mainwindow and return control on it

Comment: try with my answer. ;P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is always advisable not to mess up the code that generates Qt Designer, it is better to create another file where the logic is implemented. In addition Qt Designer generates a design class that is not a widget but serves to fill the widget. So it is recommended to create a class that implements logic and use the design.

Going to the point, if you want to close the dialog when the `QPushButton` is pressed then connect the `clicked` signal to the `close()` method. If you want to get some data of a `QDialog` one of the simplest forms is first to make the dialog is shown using the `exec_()` method since it generates its own loop and when the window is closed, the following lines of code are executed.

```
class Dialog(QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.close)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

    def onClicked(self):
        updateDialog = Dialog()
        updateDialog.exec_()
        self.lineEdit.setText(updateDialog.lineEdit.text())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

*Note: I recommend removing the changes you made in the designs or get them back with pyuic*

Comment: great this works for my test just need to implement in main code.

Comment: Sorry,can't share the project without permission but i m glad you have helped me so much and i also solved this error thanks alot :)

Answer (score 1):

You can connect the Button on your Dialog with a Function in your Main Application just like you already have done it.

Update your `connect` routine like this:

```
def connect(self):
        self.updateWindow=QtGui.QDialog()
        self.ui_update=Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui_update.setupUi(self.updateWindow)
        self.ui_update.pushButton.connect(self.printContent)
        self.updateWindow.show()
```

with

```
def printContent(self):
     print self.ui_update.lineEdit.text()
```

You should also be careful with the names of your variables. Errors will occour in the future if you use placeholders that are already taken.

Comment: i don't want to print data from the other window but return that data to mainwindown and use it